# docker amazon/aws-glue-libs permission gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, aws-glue, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a GitLab-CI with a job that contains:

```
test_glue:
  image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01
  stage: unittest
  script:
    - yum update -y && yum install -y jq blablabla
    - chmod +x script.sh
    - ./script.sh
```

However, I am getting ahat error when it hit `yum update -y && yum install -y jq blablabla`:

```
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Conflictname'
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

I am getting that error when it hit `chmod +x script.sh` *(
by removing on the top line)*:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘scripts/any.sh’: Operation not permitted
```

How can I resolve this permission issue?

*PS: in ./script.sh i have a process which use jq and more before launching spark-submit command, that park is working well*

**EDIT: I tried with sudo...`command not found`**